# How to Download from an FTP site

Tags: ftp, sco

I am using: `SCO_SV scosysv 3.2 5.0.7 i386`, and I am trying to download ssh and install it. But the only way I can do it, is by using FTP.

I have tried the following:

```
# ftp
ftp> ftp2.sco.com
?Invalid command
ftp>
```

What am I supposed to do?

I have never used FTP before in any Linux machine. I have Googled it, and I looked at every entry on the first page, and that is all talking about downloading packages from FTP sites—no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple use of the `ftp` client would be to specify the server's hostname on the command line: `ftp hostname`. Then use ftp commands `ls` and `cd [directory]` to navigate in the server's directory structure and use `get [file]` to fetch the desired file.

Notes:

1. FTP servers usually allow login for anyone, provided you use the `anonymous` username.
2. To connect to `ftp2.sco.com` specifically, you'll have to activate passive mode using `-p` option: `ftp -p ftp2.sco.com`.

Answer (score 2):

Here the list of cmds to download FILENAME from SITE_NAME:

```
ftp
open SITE_NAME
write login info
get FILENAME
```